# Sequelize hasOne Relationship association method not a function?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

I'm working on a backend that is utilizing Node and Sequelize ORM. The database being used is PostgreSQL. I've used `hasOne()` in the code before and it worked great all the `createAssociation()`, `getAssociation()` methods from the `hasOne()` relationship worked when I used it before. However for some reason it is giving me a problem now.

### index.js

```js
const Connection = new Sequelize(
  'postgres',
  'postgres',
  null,
  {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    host: '192.168.99.100',
    port: '5432',
  }
);

const ModelSeven = Connection.define('modelSeven', ModelSevenSchema),
  ModelFive = Connection.define('modelFive', ModelFiveSchema),
  ModelOne = Connection.define('modelOne', ModelOneSchema),
  ModelSix = Connection.define('modelSix', ModelSixSchema),
  ModelThree = Connection.define('modelThree', ModelThreeSchema),
  ModelFour = Connection.define('modelFour', ModelFourSchema),

ModelOne.hasOne(ModelThree); // Defines hasOne() relationship
ModelOne.hasOne(ModelFour); // Defines hasOne() relationship

ModelSix.belongsToMany(ModelOne, {through: 'Pivot'});
ModelOne.belongsToMany(ModelSix, {through: 'Pivot' });
ModelOne.belongsTo(ModelSeven);

ModelThree.hasMany(ModelFive);
ModelFour.hasMany(ModelFive);

export default Connection;
```

### utilize.js

```js
import DB from './somePathToIndex.js';

  //GraphQL resolve function
  async resolve (root, args, context) {
      //creates ModelOne 
      var ModelOne = await DB.models.ModelOne.create({
        value: args.value,
        valueTwo: args.valueTwo
      });
      // attempts to createModelThree/createModelFour from hasOne() relationship
      var ModelThree = await ModelOne.createModelThree({});
      var ModelFour = await ModelOne.createModelFour({});

      // Maps through value array finding the modelFive with and id and adding 
      // it to modelThree via hasMany() relationship
      args.value.map(async (id, key) => {
        var ModelFive = await DB.models.ModelFive.findAll({
          where: {
            id: id
          }
        });

        await ModelThree.addModelFive(ModelFive);
      });

      // Maps through value array finding the modelFive with and id and adding 
      // it to modelFour via hasMany() relationship
      args.valueTwo.map(async (id, key) => {
        var ModelFive = await DB.models.ModelFive.findAll({
          where: {
            id: id
          }
        });

        await ModelFour.addModelFive(ModelFive);
      });

      return ModelOne;
  }
```

The problem is that when node hits the line:

```
  var ModelThree = await ModelOne.createModelThree({});
  var ModelFour = await ModelOne.createModelFour({});
```

Gives me the following error:

```
"errors": [
   {
     "message": "ModelOne.createModelThree is not a function",
     "locations": [
       {
         "line": 38,
         "column": 3
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

This error is saying that the `hasOne()` relationship method `create[Association]()` is not a function. I cannot really tell why this is. If you know why please let me know.

Comment: Could you add how the files are included in each other? Looks like the relations-file index.js does not set the model relations for utilize.js.

Comment: Show your model definition, I think inflection is messing this up

Comment: @SteffenLanger I edited and added what you asked please let me know if this is alright, or wanted something else.

Comment: @Sushant I edited and added what you asked please let me know if this is alright, or wanted something else.

Comment: That's kind of what I was looking for. However, it now looks as though utilize.js includes itself. Does utilize include index.js?

Comment: @SteffenLanger my bad it meant to be import for connection in index. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Thank you.
Could this be a capitalization issue? If you define('modelOne', schema), the model should be available at DB.models.modelOne instead of DB.models.ModelOne. I'm just wondering why the error is not thrown at `var ModelOne = await DB.models.ModelOne.create()`.
Is that your real code or did you make your code more abstract?

Comment: Its abstract, I changed the names of everything to Model[number]